# How to fetch only few dependencies among many from a seperate repo in java?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, cloudera

I have the following pom.xml file

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ActionDataInterpret</groupId>
  <artifactId>ActionDataInterpret</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <jdkLevel>1.6</jdkLevel>
    <requiredMavenVersion>[2.1,)</requiredMavenVersion>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${jdkLevel}</source>
          <target>${jdkLevel}</target>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <!--<exclude>storm:*</exclude> -->
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ComponentsXmlResourceTransformer" />
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>


  <sourceDirectory>/home/user/workspace/ActionDataInterpret</sourceDirectory>
</build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
      <version>0.94.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.6</version>
                </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

However, i want only hadoop and hbase to be fetched from the cloudera repo and not from the default maven repo..

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: any specific reason that you don't want to get the artifacts from Maven Central Repo ??

Comment: I'm running the application on Cloudera Cluster.. So i want the jars to be fetched from cloudera repo ..

Answer (score 0):

I think with the repositories you can configure that , it will first try to download the artifact from your mentioned repository url , if it is not available their then it try to download from Maven Central Repo.

Add the repositories under your project in pom.xml

```
 <repositories>
   <repository>
   <id>cloudera</id>
   <url>Your Cloudera Specific Location</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

For more you can refer maven specs [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html).

Try with this .